# Given two fixed sets of orthonormal bases, is there a unique "best" representation for a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

As an example in 2D, take the Cartesian base $(\vec e_x, \vec e_y)$, and *one* other base $(\vec e_1, \vec e_2)$ rotated by one *fixed* angle $\phi\neq0$ (e.g. $\phi=45°$), i.e. $$\begin{pmatrix}\vec e_1\\\vec e_2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\cos\phi & \sin\phi \\ -\sin\phi & \cos\phi \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\vec e_x\\\vec e_y\end{pmatrix}.$$ Given a vector $\vec a$, how to determine whether its representation is "better" in the original base or the rotated one? With better I mean some measure that I am not sure how to express, e.g. should a specific $l_p$-Norm be extremalized? Take $\vec a = \vec e_1$, in which case the rotated base is "better" since only one base vector is required to express $\vec a$, while for a vector close to $\vec e_x$ the Cartesian representation might be "better". It is clear that for ONBs the $l_2$-norm is invariant, while e.g. $$l_1(\vec e_1) = \begin{cases}1 & (\vec e_1,\vec e_2)\text{-base} \\ |\cos\phi| + |\sin\phi| > 1 & (\vec e_x,\vec e_y)\text{-base}\end{cases},\\
l_4(\vec e_1) = \begin{cases}1 & (\vec e_1,\vec e_2)\text{-base} \\ \sqrt[4]{\cos^4\phi + \sin^4\phi} < 1 & (\vec e_x,\vec e_y)\text{-base}\end{cases}$$

But in a general context, is selecting the base such that $l_1$ is minimal *always* equivalent to maximizing $l_p$ for $p > 2$?

Comment: There is no canonical choice of basis for a vector space. The best basis within which to represent a vector would be one that contained that vector as a basis element.

Comment: @FlybyNight True, but if the choice is between only two different _fixed_ bases that freedom is not given

Comment: Perhaps that could be made a little clearer in your post. Your post seems to examine a one-parameter family of bases, not simply two.

Comment: @FlybyNight Ah yes, thanks for pointing that out. Is it clearer now?

Comment: I think your specific question boils down to the question of given two unit vectors (in $l^2$ norm) in $\mathbb{R}^n$, can one of the vectors have smaller $l^1$ and $l^p$ norm simultaneously?

Comment: @Evan I can't follow you to that conclusion, in my example I'm minimizing $l^1$ but maximizing $l^{p>2}$ - minimizing both $l^1$ and $l^p$ simultaneously for an _arbitrary_ vector won't work due to $||\vec a||_p \le ||\vec a||_{p+\epsilon}$ (with the exception of a unit vector where $||\vec e||_p \equiv 1$)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler   Hmm, but it's not true that if $\|a\|_1 \leq \|b\|_1$  implies $\|a\|_p \geq \|b\|_p$ for $p>2$. But I guess the extra unit norm constraint might impose that? Ah and also, here I am really not thinking about bases at all, since for a fixed vector, there is some basis whose coefficients will be $a$  and another basis whose coefficients will be $b$.

Comment: @Evan Hm, it might actually be in interesting question whether $||a||_1=||a||_2=1$ implies $||a||_p\equiv 1$ for all $p$. Though my guess is yes, since $l^2$ implies a unit vector and $l^1$ should imply that exactly one component equals one. Re your second point, I am thinking about two fixed sets of bases and an arbitrary amount of vectors for each of which I want to find the "shorter" representation

Comment: @TobiasKienzler This is true. Just need to use the fact that all entries $\leq 1$, then in the expression for the $l^2$ norm, if you sum a bunch of terms raised to the $2$nd power, it strictly reduces the sum compared to the $l^1$ norm unless the terms are $1$. But at most one term can be $1$, as you observe.  About the second point: For a single vector, writing them in your two bases, $a$ can be coefficients in one basis and $b$ can be coefficients in the other. That is what I meant to say.